# Handle Spring REST separated Frontend/backend post request

Tags: spring, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to develop a RESTful webservice with Spring using 2 different projects for backend/webservice and frontend.

In the backend project I implemented the model

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id_user", nullable = false)
    private String id;
    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false)
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "firstname", nullable = false)
    private String firstname;
    @Column(name = "lastname", nullable = false)
    private String lastname;
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "own_printer", nullable = false)
    private Boolean ownsPrinter;

    // Getters Setters...
}
```

There is also a UserDAO class to access database (through Hibernate 4) and a UserManager for business processes. And then a UserController:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    private UserService userService ;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/listusers")
    List<User> getAllUser() {
        Application.context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        userService = (UserService) Application.context.getBean("userService");

        List<User> users = userService.getUsers();  
        return users;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{userid}")
    User getUserById(@PathVariable("userid") String userId) {
        Application.context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        userService = (UserService) Application.context.getBean("userService");
        User user = userService.getUserById(userId);    
        return user;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/add")
    @ResponseBody
    User signUpUser(@RequestBody User user ) {
        // Don't really know what to do...
        userService = (UserService) Application.context.getBean("userService");
        return user;
    }

}
```

And now for the frontend projects I implemented the same User class. And I wrote a UserDAO UserManager and UserController classes:

```
//UserDAO.java

@Repository("userDAO")
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO{
    @Override
    public ArrayList<User> getUsers() {
        //User[] users = new RestTemplate().getForEntity(WebService.getWebServiceUrl() + "users", User[].class).getBody();
        ArrayList<User> user = new RestTemplate().getForEntity(WebService.getWebServiceUrl() + "listusers", ArrayList.class).getBody();

        return (user);
        //return Arrays.asList(users);
    }

    @Override
    public User getUserById(String userId) {
        User user = new RestTemplate().getForEntity(WebService.getWebServiceUrl() + "user/" + userId, User.class).getBody();
        return user;
    }

    @Override
    public void insertUser(User user) {
        // doesn't work
        RestTemplate template = new RestTempl   ate();
        template.postForObject(WebService.getWebServiceUrl() + "user/add",user, String.class);
        System.out.println(user.toString());
    }
}



//UserController.java

@Controller
public class UserController {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);

    private UserService userService = new UserServiceImpl();

    @RequestMapping(value = "/listusers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listUsers(@RequestParam(required=false)Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Users page", locale);
        ArrayList<User> users = userService.getUsers(); 
        model.addAttribute("users", users);
        return "listusers";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{user_id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String singleUser(@RequestParam(required=false)Locale locale, 
            Model model,HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam String id) {
        logger.info("User page", locale);
        User user = userService.getUserById(id);
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        return "user";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listPersons(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        return "signup";
    }

    //For add and update person both
    @RequestMapping(value= "/user/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public void saveUser(Model model, @ModelAttribute("user") User u){
         RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();
         rt.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
         rt.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());

         String uri = new String(WebService.getWebServiceUrl() + "user/add");

         User user = new User();
         user = u;

         User returns = rt.postForObject(uri, u, User.class);
    }
}
```

The get requests work: I get to display my list of users. But my problem is that I can't get to pass data from the frontend part to the backend webservice part with a post request... I'have been trying several solutions but I think there is something wrong with something else.

I'm kinda new in the world of JavaEE applications. Can someone help me or guide me to a solution ?

Comment: can you show us your front end part?I mean how are u making call to spring services

Answer (score 0):

In the Frontend UserDAO:

```
public ArrayList<User> getUsers() {
    ArrayList<User> user = new RestTemplate().getForEntity(WebService.getWebServiceUrl() + "listusers", ArrayList.class).getBody();
    return (user);
}
```

This code allows to request the server through the uri "/listuser". On the frontEnd UserController you can see the function that call getUsers():

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/listusers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listUsers(@RequestParam(required=false)Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Users page", locale);
        ArrayList<User> users = userService.getUsers(); 
        model.addAttribute("users", users);
        return "listusers";
    }
```

And then in the backend the function that route this url:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/listusers")
    List<User> getAllUser() {
        Application.context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        userService = (UserService) Application.context.getBean("userService");

        List<User> users = userService.getUsers();  
        return users;
    }
```

After this, teh backend UserDAO class access to database.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the URL you are posting to at the frontend. You are using the same URL for posting to frontend (UserDAO) and backend (UserController) : WebService.getWebServiceUrl()

[EDIT]
You have two POST services as /user/add/ , If you are exposing them on the same url, it is a conflict. Probably your backend will be hosted on another port or another server. You should use that url to hit the backend service from frontend.

[EDIT 2]
Yes for listusers you are not making a REST call from frontend. You are calling the JAVA API userService. But for add user, you are making a REST call from frontend to backend once again

Comment: Shouldn't I do this  ?